Parallel line equation
I want to incorporate 2 diagonal lines in a logo design. The lines have to be parallel to each other and have to be exactly 0.5 inches apart when measured perpendicular. The upper point of Line 1 has to be fixed at one intersection on Point A. The lower point of Line 2 has to be fixed at a different intersection on Point D. How would I calculate Point B and Point C?


Clearly $AB=CD$. It will be affected by the vertical distance of $AB$ above $BC$.

I understand that if I solve for one I can also solve for the other. My question is, what's the equation I would use to solve for B or C. Assume a vertical distance of 3" between the points.

Here is one possible geometric construction, which could be done in CAD software.
Draw a circle of radius $0.5$ around $A$. Then the line $BD$ will be tangent to this circle. To find the point $E$ of tangency, note that $AED$ must be a right angle; so draw a circle with diameter $AD$, and let $E$ be where it intersects the other circle. (There are two points of intersection; choose the one on the right side.) Then $B$ will be the intersection of line $DE$ and the horizontal line through $A$. Then point $C$ can be found by completing the parallelogram.


Decided to go this route. Math isn't my strong suite and with the software I'm using, this solution works perfect. Thanks!

See the modified picture below, where I have added some lines and labels.
Since triangle CKD is similar to triangle DHB, we get the proportion
$$\frac{0.5}{CD}=\frac{3}{BD}$$
which gives $BD=6CD$.
Using Pythagorean theorem on triangle DHB, we get
$$BH^2+9=BD^2$$
so we get
$$BH^2=BD^2-9=36CD^2-9$$
Noting that $CD+CE=2.25$ and $CE=BH$, we get $CD=2.25-BH$. Continuing, we get
$$BH^2=36CD^2-9=36(2.25-BH)^2-9=36(5.0625-4.5BH+BH^2)-9$$
which gives
$$182.25-162BH+36BH^2-9=BH^2$$
Using $x=BH$, we need to solve
$$35x^2-162x+173.25=0$$
The quadratic formula yields
$$BH=CE=x=\frac{162\pm\sqrt{162^2-4(35)(173.25)}}{70}$$
This gives the two solutions 1.6772 and 2.9514. The bigger one here seems to not be possible based on the drawing. So I'd vote for 1.6772 for BH. This seems to give $AB=2.25-BH=0.5728$.


Draw a line perpendicular to line BD, emanating from point C. From trig in the resulting triangle, it follows that
$$d=AB \sin (C\hat{D}B)$$
where d is the distance between lines $AC, BD$ and from the right triangle formed by the vertical emanating from point D and the extension of segment AB
$$\sin (C\hat{D}B)=\frac{h}{\sqrt{(b+a-AB)^2+h^2}}$$
Here $h=3'', b=2'', a=0.25''$ as read from the diagram, and they represent the vertical distance, the box length and the margin respectively. Putting everything together and $AB=x$ we have to solve the quadratic equation
$$(b+a-x)^2+h^2=x^2\frac{h^2}{d^2}$$
Plugging in yields a single positive solution, $AB\approx 0.573''$.

Don't you mean sin instead of cos in the first equation?

yes, corrected.

Maybe cos in the second equation though? I'm trying to follow

Corrected the typos. I think you should be able to follow now.

Okay cool, looks like we agree on the answer then

Your equation is very straight forward and I understand what all the variables mean. That being said, could you guide me through the process of solving it. Like I said before in a previous comment; math isn't my strong suit. I would like to be able to understand and solve this equation though. Thanks!

Getting better at math sometimes means to put in the work to fill in the steps presented. If you decide to work through this and have specific questions, I'll be happy to answer!

I don't understand how AB = d sin( angle CDB), if d is the perpendicular distance and AB is the hypotenuse then d=AB sin( angle CDB)???

Thanks for finding the typo @Eular, it does not affect the final solution.

Actually, you accidentally wrote the right thing in the final equation earlier; that's why the final result did not change.
